# async_callback problems involving mutex

Tags: c, concurrency, mutex

I am having hard time trying to solve the concurrency problem:

> Assume in a system, users will register a callback function with
>   system and that callback function will be called when an event is
>   triggered but if the event is already triggered, the user will
>   synchronously call the callback function.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> suppose user i registers cb i at time Ti,
> and the event happens at time Te
> and assume that T1 < T2 < T3 <...< Tm < Te < Tm+1 < ... < Tn
> at time Te, cb1..cbm will be called
> cbm+1 .. cbn will be called synchronously
> implement two APIs: void register_cb (cb), and void event_trigger()
> ```

Currently, my solution is:

```
is_triggered = false;
mutex_a = 1

void event_trigger(){
    aquire(mutex_a); 
    is_triggered = true;
    while(!q.empty()){
        cb = q.top();
        q.pop();
        cb();
    ｝
    release(mutex_a);     
｝

void register_cb(cb){
   aquire(mutex_a);
   if(is_triggered) 
         release(mutex_a);
         cb();       
   else{
         q.push(cb);
         release(mutex_a);
   }
}
```

But this does not solve the problem: I think I have misplaced the mutex. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding "but if the event is already triggered, the user will synchronously call the callback" because that means the user didn't register the callback (he is calling it himself) and the user knows the event is in progress. Could you be more clear on this? Also please identify where in the sequence of T1..Tn is Ti.

Comment: Can you edit the code in your question? The indentation is all wrong and you have more `{` than `}`.

Comment: Any how, you need to release the mutex after the `while` loop, not inside the `while` loop.

Comment: just edit the code, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Try my best to clarify: I think the problem is asking: user could register those callback functions before a certain event happens, and after that that event is triggered, all the call back function that is registered after that event will be executed synchronously. Is that helpful?

Comment: What I see of your code now is that `event_trigger()` is a function that returns `int` but I don't see a `return` statement - your compiler should complain. The same holds for `register_cb(cb)` which takes a parameter supposedly to be `int` and again has no `return` statement. If this code is inside a function, then a block is unconditionally executed after `event_trigger()` and after `register_cb(cb)`. Please fix the code.

Comment: You should add details explaining *why* you think this solution is wrong: what unexpected behavior are you seeing?